# Find the smallest number for which the number divides completely into 101

Tags: binomial-coefficients, divisibility

> Find the smallest number $n,(n>4)$,
>   $A=\binom{3n-1}{11}+\binom{3n-1}{12}+\binom{3n}{13}+\binom{3n+1}{14}$
>   for which the number divides completely into $101$.

My solution:
$\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k+1}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}\\\binom{3n-1}{11}+\binom{3n-1}{12}=\binom{3n}{12}\\\binom{3n}{12}+\binom{3n}{13}=\binom{3n+1}{13}\\\binom{3n+1}{13}+\binom{3n+1}{14}=\binom{3n+2}{14}\\\binom{3n+2}{14}=\frac{(3n+2)!}{14!(3n+2-14)!}=\frac{(3n+2)!}{14!(3n-12)!}$

and at the moment I don't know how to do the task efficiently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** You're almost there.  Since $101$ is a prime number, it will divide $\ \frac{(3n+2)!}{14!(3n-12)!}\ $ evenly if and only if it divides one of the numbers $\ 3n+2,3n+1, 3n, \dots,3n-11\ $.

Comment: For example $3*33+2=101$ 
How can I be sure that this is the smallest number? And 14! doesn't disturb divisibility?

Comment: If $101$ divides one of the numbers $\ 3n+2,3n+1,3n, \dots,$$3n-11\ $, then $\ 3n+2\ $ cannot be smaller than $101$. Therefore, $\ \frac{(3n+2)!}{14!(3n-12)!}\ $ cannot be smaller than $\ \frac{101\cdot100\cdot\,\dots\,\cdot88}{14!}\ $.

The only prime factors of $\ (3n+2)(3n+1)\dots(3n-11)\ $ which can be cancelled out by the $\ 14!\ $ are $\ 2,3,5,7,11\ $ and $\ 13\ $, so if $101$ is a factor of $\ (3n+2)(3n+1)\dots(3n-11)\ $ it will still be a factor of $\ \frac{(3n+2)(3n+1)\dots(3n-11)}{14!}\ $.